# Python Woocommerce : {'code': 'woocommerce_product_invalid_image_id', 'message': '#0 is an invalid image ID.', 'data': {'status': 400}}

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, woocommerce

I'm trying import products from another site into my woocommerce site through Woocommerce API, it used to work before but now it's throwing below error, how do you fix this ?

```
{'code': 'woocommerce_product_invalid_image_id', 'message': '#0 is an invalid image ID.', 'data': {'status': 400}}
```

Python script :

```
getdetailallimage =['https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1QlOUKbuWBuNjSszgq6z8jVXaa/GUFEATHER-L45-3-5-4cm-Tassel-jewelry-accessories-accessories-parts-diy-hand-made-jewelry-findings-embellishments.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1TnudB2uSBuNkHFqDq6xfhVXav/GUFEATHER-L45-3-5-4cm-Tassel-jewelry-accessories-accessories-parts-diy-hand-made-jewelry-findings-embellishments.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Nc0BBZuYBuNkSmRyq6AA3pXay/GUFEATHER-L45-3-5-4cm-Tassel-jewelry-accessories-accessories-parts-diy-hand-made-jewelry-findings-embellishments.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB151.8QVXXXXazXXXXq6xXFXXXm/GUFEATHER-L45-3-5-4cm-Tassel-jewelry-accessories-accessories-parts-diy-hand-made-jewelry-findings-embellishments.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1rJwuQVXXXXacaXXXq6xXFXXX0/GUFEATHER-L45-3-5-4cm-Tassel-jewelry-accessories-accessories-parts-diy-hand-made-jewelry-findings-embellishments.jpg', 'https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1qmprB2iSBuNkSnhJq6zDcpXav/GUFEATHER-L45-3-5-4cm-Tassel-jewelry-accessories-accessories-parts-diy-hand-made-jewelry-findings-embellishments.jpg']

data = {
                    "name": "productitles",
                    "type": "simple",
                    "sku":str(productids),
                    "regular_price": str(conint),
                    "description": "",
                    "short_description": "",
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "id": "categoryID"
                        }
                    ],
                    "images": []
                }

                [data["images"].append({"src": li, "position": getdetailallimage.index(li)}) for li in getdetailallimage]
print(wcapi.post("products", data).json())
```

Comment: See if this is related to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54353205/woocommerce-3-5-4-and-wordpress-5-0-3-rest-api-image-upload-broken-woocommerce