# WooCommerce 3.5.4 and WordPress 5.0.3 REST API: Image upload broken (woocommerce_product_invalid_image_id)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using v2 of the REST API. This code worked fine on an older version of WordPress and WooCommerce. I cannot upload an image to a product.

The first error after the upgrade I got was:

```
array (
  'code' => 'woocommerce_product_image_upload_error',
  'message' => 'Invalid image: Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.',
  'data' => 
  array (
    'status' => 400,
  ),
```

Resolved by adding following in `wp-config.php` to the bottom of the file:

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

The 2nd error I cannot figure out. The image won't upload and leaves a ghost image where it was uploaded.

**Code**

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://localhost/wordpress', 
    'ck_44b92c00ea35e6cc59c89c29051bf67c22e0df3a', 
    'cs_dd833592a1ef7a00a82c1711fd455db2e4c5bd15',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v2',
    ]
);

$data['create'][] = array(
    'name' => 'TEST',
    'regular_price' => '4.50',
    'description' => 'TEST DESC',
    'type' => 'simple',
    'images' => array(
        array(
            'alt' => '',
            'name' => '',
            'src' => 'http://demo2.phppointofsale.com/PHP-Point-Of-Sale-Prev/index.php/app_files/view/1',
            'position' => 0,
        ),
    )
);


$response = $woocommerce->post('products/batch',$data);
$headers = $woocommerce->http->getResponse()->getHeaders();
var_dump($headers);
var_dump($response);
```

**Response Data**

```
array(13) {
  ["Date"]=>
  string(29) "Thu, 24 Jan 2019 18:22:16 GMT"
  ["Server"]=>
  string(6) "Apache"
  ["X-Powered-By"]=>
  string(9) "PHP/7.2.1"
  ["X-Robots-Tag"]=>
  string(7) "noindex"
  ["Link"]=>
  string(63) "<http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/""
  ["X-Content-Type-Options"]=>
  string(7) "nosniff"
  ["Access-Control-Expose-Headers"]=>
  string(27) "X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages"
  ["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"]=>
  string(27) "Authorization, Content-Type"
  ["Expires"]=>
  string(29) "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
  ["Cache-Control"]=>
  string(36) "no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
  ["Allow"]=>
  string(16) "POST, PUT, PATCH"
  ["Content-Length"]=>
  string(3) "139"
  ["Content-Type"]=>
  string(31) "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
}
array(1) {
  ["create"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(0)
      ["error"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(36) "woocommerce_product_invalid_image_id"
        ["message"]=>
        string(27) "#82 is an invalid image ID."
        ["data"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["status"]=>
          int(400)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Proof https://via.placeholder.com/350x150 is an image

```
cmuench@cmuench:~$ curl -I "https://via.placeholder.com/350x150";
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Mon, 28 Jan 2019 14:07:22 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 1253
Last-Modified: Sun, 06 Jan 2019 22:00:10 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5c327a6a-4e5"
Expires: Mon, 04 Feb 2019 14:07:22 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
X-Cache: L1
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

http://demo2.phppointofsale.com/PHP-Point-Of-Sale-Prev/index.php/app_files/view/1

headers from actual files (not demo example). Same error as demo example

```
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000");
    header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', strtotime('+1 month')).' GMT');
    header('Pragma: cache');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
    header("Content-type: ".get_mime_by_extension($file->file_name));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

even the remote server returns "Content-Type: image/png", Wordpress's server side retrieval function did not get the file name because lack of the name in your rest request and no filename in the remote server response, which cause the internal wp_attachment_is_image() test failed. Try set the rest request with file name with proper file extension.

refer to the woocommerce source code:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/00a93ae8f0b200b4def4aea4462fec9d1d5ea96c/includes/api/v2/class-wc-rest-products-v2-controller.php

and Wordpress code:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.3/src/wp-includes/post.php

Comment: The image I gave you in the test was not the actual image I use when I pull in images. I have updated you with headers I use which does include filename

Comment: you need to include file extension like .png .jpg etc. in the name or the url of images in REST request.

Comment: That really doesn’t make a lot of sense. These are valid images

Comment: check wc source code wc-rest-functions.php line 67, they use wc_rest_upload_image_from_url to deal with image from url, and looking for filename in the url, you might can file a bug report with them then.

Answer (score 2):

Because the url doesn't include a file extension in it's name, Wordpress treats it as a file with no extension thus failing the `wp_check_filetype_and_ext` test.

You can add a filter to add the correct file extension where non exists in the url

```
add_filter('wp_handle_sideload_prefilter', 'add_extension_if_none_exists');

function add_extension_if_none_exists($file){
    if ( pathinfo( $file['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) ) {
        return $file;
    }
    $real_mime = wp_get_image_mime( $file['tmp_name'] );
    $mime_to_ext = apply_filters(
        'getimagesize_mimes_to_exts',
        array(
            'image/jpeg' => 'jpg',
            'image/png'  => 'png',
            'image/gif'  => 'gif',
            'image/bmp'  => 'bmp',
            'image/tiff' => 'tif',
            'image/webp' => 'webp',
        )
    );
    if ( ! empty( $mime_to_ext[ $real_mime ] ) ) {
        $file['name'] .= '.' . $mime_to_ext[ $real_mime ];
    }
    return $file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just setup a similar environment, your code works, the problem lies with your image link, curl seems to get the url response as html rather than an image (https://via.placeholder.com/350x150). From the docs "src" is a string containing Image URL unfortunately the string you provide is NOT an image url.You'll just need to point to image files directly the code below works fine for me.

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;

$woocommerce = new Client(
    'http://localhost/wordpress', 
    'ck_a3ec02fcd547837c384e43ee6989200cca8f6178', 
    'cs_f60e9ad5c93c9e3bd4adaabd4bd323edddb58f7b',
    [
        'wp_api' => true,
        'version' => 'wc/v2',
    ]
);

$data['create'][] = array(
    'name' => 'TEST',
    'regular_price' => '4.50',
    'description' => 'TEST DESC',
    'type' => 'simple',
    'images' => array(
        array(
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg',

        ),
    )
);


$response = $woocommerce->post('products/batch',$data);
$headers = $woocommerce->http->getResponse()->getHeaders();
var_dump($headers);
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: https://via.placeholder.com/350x150 is an image. I have tried with multiple images that don't have a file extension and it doesn't work. I have updated my question with curl headers

Comment: The answer should say it requires a valid file extension in URL

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bug on WooCommerce on the version you're using. If it's the case: If you are uploading a new image by using an external URL, you should include id field and set it to "0"

```
"images": [
        {
            "src": "http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg",
            "id": "0"
        }
    ]
```

If you are using an image from your WordPress media, you should set the id of the image along with the link on WP there.